# Installing integrated type apps on android device and wearable device

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-galaxy-gear

I have a android app and a tizen wearable app. I have successfully tested them on my android device (Samsung S4) and the Tizen Emulator. Now, I want to try installing the wearable app on my Gear 2 device as well and connected it.

I tried installing the wearable app on the Gear 2 and it worked but it wasn't connected to the Android device (Because HostManagerForEmul) says "Disconnected". I dont know how to connect my two devices, any suggestions? Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have "gear manager" installed on your phone? If not then install it from "Galaxy App Store". Then run gear manager app, in that you would get option to connect with your gear.

Steps to connect

1. Open gear manager
2. Click on three vertical dots present on top right hand side and then select "Manage Devices" option. (Check first screenshot )
3. Select your device from list of available devices. (Check 2nd screenshot )

[image: refer for step 2]

[image: Refer for step 3]

Note- If you are facing any problem related to installing Gear Manager, then please once go through the comments below.

Comment: I uninstalled it before so that I could use the HostManagerForEmul but now I can't install the Gear Manager, it says "installation failed try later(-112)"

Comment: Ok. Could you please check none of the apps related to gear manager is present in your phone. Please check in Settings->Application Manager. Because Gear manager installs many dependent packages/app. Please uninstall all dependent pkgs/apps. Then restart your phone and try installing gear manager.

Comment: Im not sure which gear manager related apps are though. Is it these? ConnectionManager, Gear Plugin, goproviders, HostManager, SAFileTransferCore,Samsung Accessory Service, saproviders ,Update Gear software, WeatherProvider

Comment: Yes. Whichever is having similar icon as gear manager - ConnectionManager, Gear Plugin, goproviders, HostManager, SAFileTransferCore,Samsung Accessory Service, saproviders ,Update Gear software, call provider, gear module. All these you uninstall.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer from @srkushwaha so other users know this is an accepted solution.